# Cells are not deselected with swipe gesture

Tags: swift

I have three cells within a table view that the user can tap that segue to three view controllers. I have just noticed that when I use the swipe gesture to go back to the table view from one of the view controllers, sometimes the cells are not deselected.

The cells are deselected when the back button is tapped and when the swipe gesture is performed slowly. However the cells are not deselected when the swipe gesture is performed quickly.

I'm using Swift by the way.

Is this an iOS 8 bug or is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me. Workaround:

```
override func viewDidDisappear() {
   super.viewDidDisappear()
   tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(lastIndexPath, animated: false)
}
```

after having saved the last selected index path in `lastIndexPath`.